# Android: Borders of image got distorted after ImageView Rotation

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am using `"android:rotation="5"` in the XML file for `ImageView` and image is rotated by 5 degrees. But the border of the `ImageView` is distorted.

Any suggestions to resolve this?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Do you have an image showing the issue? Are you seeing the same thing when applying a rotation matrix to ImageView's 'setImageMatrix` method?

Comment: add screen shot with issue

Comment: My ImageView is like this: `<ImageView
 android:layout_width="100dp"
 android:layout_height="100dp"
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_icon"
 android:id="@+id/ivPhoto"
 android:rotation="5"
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
 android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
 android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
 android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
 android:padding="2dp"/>`